# My android app -that uses my pc as server- does not work when my android phone is connected to a network outside my local network

Tags: android, http, netbeans, server, ip

I have developed an android app in android studio and Netbeans. I don't have a server or a virtual machine to establish all what is needed to run the application. So, I use my pc as server. The code for the server is on Netbeans, where glassfish is used. I have used my private ip like this in Android studio:

//AsyncTask for signIn

final static String url = "http://192.168.1.32:8080/app_server/Controller?action=signIn";

app_server is the netbeans web project. It works fine that way, only if my android phone is connected to my Wi-fi.

So, my question is how to make the app work in any phone with different network connections than mine connection. if I use my public ip(which is dynamic), it won't work nor with my Wi-fi connection.

The database is on localhost, port 3306(if it matters)

I' ve seen several solutions regarding dynamic dns server, port forwarding, making dynamic ip static, etc. I' ve tried to do some of these things with no result(probably I'm doing something wrong). What do you suggest to me;

Thank you and sorry if I' m asking something trivial.

Comment: You're using a non-public NATed IP for the server.  You'd need a public IP for it, with no firewalls in between.  Which given you didn't immediately know this, I highly suggest you don't even try to do-  I doubt you could do it securely.  And I doubt your ISP would let you if you're on a residential network.

Comment: Basically, any IP that starts with 192.168, 172.16-172.31, or 10.  are reserved for local area networks and can't be reached from the outside.  You can access the outside like that via a NAT, which is a device with a public IP that will forward data from you and pretend its from it, and send it back to the correct receiver on the inside.  Most home routers have NAT built in.  But you can't use a computer behind one of these as a server, because there's no way to address it-  unless you open up a hole in the NAT and tell it all traffic on port X goes to IP Y

Comment: Also, please note that your IP received via DNS for your router may change at any time, without warning, which will break your app even if you poke a hole.  So basically-  if you need to access it over the internet, its time to move to a real server in AWS or the like.

Comment: Do you have a website hosting account?  Many of those accounts will allow you to install web apps such as the one you are describing, and the fee for such an account is probably less than $10 a month.  Bottom line is you need your web app to be exposed to the internet for it to be reached by a phone over 3/4G

Comment: Thank you for your quick responses. So, you are telling me that it is not worth trying to use my pc as server for the described app. But that is achievable somehow, right? So, till I move to a real server in order to publish the app, I would like to have the ability to demonstrate the app to someone. Is there a way to demonstrate the described app to someone, using virtual box for example(or something else)?